# How to hide clicked element when all having same parent class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to hide caption of particular slide which user clicked. Here having same class name for all the slides is making big problem. How to over come this.

```
<div id="accordion-wrapper">
                <div class="slide">
                    <div id="mask"></div> <img src="snd/images/slider1.jpg" />
                    <div class="caption">
                        <p> 1</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <div id="mask"></div> <img src="snd/images/slider2.jpg" />
                    <div class="caption">
                        <p> 2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <div id="mask"></div> <img src="snd/images/slider3.jpg" />
                    <div class="caption">
                        <p> 3</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <div id="mask"></div> <img src="snd/images/slider4.jpg" />
                    <div class="caption">
                        <p> 4</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <div id="mask"></div> <img src="snd/images/slider5.jpg" />
                    <div class="caption">
                        <p> 5</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Use `this` or `$(this)`. Where's JS code? **[mcve]** Anyway, use `$(this).closest('.slide').hide();`

Comment: ids must be unique. There's `id='mask'` on every slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".slide").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".caption").hide();
})
```

Comment: But it will also hide all the .caption of other slides. I want to hide only clicked slide caption to hide where remaining should be displayed as usual

Comment: $(this).find(".caption") will only select the child '.caption' of the slide clicked. So it won't hide all the other captions.